# Android Web Services - Async Task

Tags: android, web-services, rest, android-asynctask

I'm very new to android technologies. I've recently read that android only allows a REST web service invocation from inside an AsyncTask... Is this true?? I'm developing an app for the university, I have to finish it for tomorrow and I would realy like to know if I can just call the REST WS inside an ordinary function, despite the fact that it may not be a good practice...

Thank you in advice!!
José.

Comment: Did it ever occur to you that you could have tried it yourself to put the operation where you wanted it and see what happens?

Comment: I didn't have the Web Services yet, a friend of mine was developing them and I wanted to do some work meanwhile. Arrest me if I'm a thief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that you may not call it on the UI-thread (otherwise you will get an exception). Besides this restriction, it does not matter from where you call it.

A benefit of using `AsyncTask`s is that they are a very easy way of using additional threads in Android, since it comes with many callbacks (which are run on the UI-thread)

Another alternative could be to use an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: so there is no possible way of just executing the web-service call in the UI-thread? I have to make ALL the calls from another thread? is this a real tech-limitation from android or just a matter of good practices?

Comment: @user2471107 You can always perform network operations in the UI thread. However, the app will not response to any clicks nor any interactions while the network request is doing its thing. You will end up having a "Application Not Responding" error dialog too. You definitely DO NOT want that. Also, some devices give you an error when you try to perform network tasks in UI thread, preventing you from doing so.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I was not aware that there actually are some devices that allows you to have network operations on UI-thread, I've always gotten the "Network on UI-thread"-exception.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Sorry I was meant to say "some android versions". If you look at the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) here, the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` was introduced since API 11.